# extracting a variable from the redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I need to extract the props from the store in the ***calculate*** component and pass the calculation results in the ***app***. I just started using redux.

> app.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import principalChanged from './src/actions';
    import { Input, Card } from './src/components/common';
    import  { principal2, principal3 } from './src/components/calculate';

      class App extends Component {
        onPrincipalChange(text) {           
          this.props.principalChanged(text); 
        }
      render() {
        return ( 
            <Card>
               <Input 
                 placeholder="Placeholder" 
                 label="Label" 
                 onChangeText={this.onPrincipalChange.bind(this)} 
                 value={this.props.principal}                      
                />
              `Current state of the variable: ${this.props.principal}`{/n}
              `New variable: ${principal2}`
              `New variable: ${principal3}`
            </Card>
        );
       }
       }
const mapStateToProps = state => { 
   return { 
      principal: state.form.principal
   }; 
}; 
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { 
    principalChanged 
})(App);
```

> calculate.js

```
// call the { principal } variable from the store
// somehow 
// maybe I should use mergeProps
export const principal2 = (principal) => {     
     return ( { principal * 2 } ); // calculating 
}; 

export const principal3 = () => {     
     return ( { principal2 / 4 } ); // calculating
};
```

I don't know how to connect state.principal.props to ***calculate.js***. Maybe I should use mergeProps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't connect Redux (resp. react-redux) store to a function. You have to always connect it to a component via connect. Which you correctly used in App component.

What you're looking for is called a selector, or a selector-like logic. Just call the transform functions in the connect and thus inject the values you need in your component. No need to use mergeProps.

Here is how you may do it, code should be exacutable:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import principalChanged from './src/actions';
import { Input, Card } from './src/components/common';
import { principal2 as principal2Selector, principal3 as principal3Selector } from './src/components/calculate';

class App extends Component {

  onPrincipalChange(text) {           
    this.props.principalChanged(text); 
  }

  render() {
    const { principal, principal2, principal3 } = this.props

    return ( 
      <Card>
        <Input 
          placeholder="Placeholder" 
          label="Label" 
          onChangeText={this.onPrincipalChange.bind(this)} 
          value={principal}                      
        />
        Current state of the variable: {principal}
        New variable: {principal2}
        New variable: {principal3}
      </Card>
    );
  }
}



const mapStateToProps = state => { 
  const principal = state.form.principal 

  return {
    principal,
    principal2: principal2Selector(principal),
    principal3: principal3Selector(principal),
  } 
}; 

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { 
    principalChanged 
})(App);
```

Just mind I renamed your *principal2* and *principal3* imports, not to confuse the variables with functions/selectors.

```
import { principal2 as principal2Selector, principal3 as principal3Selector } from './src/components/calculate';
```

**calculate.js**

```
export const principal2 = (principal) => {     
     return (principal * 2); // calculating 
}; 

export const principal3 = (principal) => {     
     return (principal2(principal) / 4); // calculating
};
```

Comment: Keep it as it is. Just make the functions take *principal* as a parameter. I edited my answer. Look above.

Comment: But I cant change principal props now((. It works just whith init props. I'll try find a solution

Comment: Of course you can. In this example, Redux store is your single source of truth. All the data, you're working with come from Redux store. As long as principalChanged action correctly updates the data in the store, App component will re-render with updated data. That's the whole point of redux, resp. react-redux. Try to investigate, if your principalChanged action correctly changes stored data.

Comment: The problem was when I replaced `this.props.principal` to `principal` by _ctrl->h_. It replaced body in `onPrincipalChange`. You right. My apology.   But I discovered that   `const principal2 = principal2Selector(this.props.principal);    const principal3 = principal3Selector(this.props.principal); `  works too before first `return` condition. Not necessary do it in _**connect**_. What way for your opinion will be faster?

Comment: At all I want to place whole logic in calculate.js, then export variables to app.js. Actually I have a lot reducers. Not only principal value had changed.  New variables have dependencies from all reducers.

Comment: Ad1) It will work even if you retrieve the values outside of connect, of course. It's a matter of preference. Ad2) Putting the logic into pure functions inside calculate.js is the correct way to think. I suggest you to look into what "Redux selectors" are. This is the way you are, and should be heading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [actions](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html) and [reducers](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html)

Basically, in some part of your code you need to dispatch an action and resolve it with your reducer.

So you will need to create the action file and the reducer file for solve calculate and the root reducer to import this reducer and another that you will have.

Obs.: consider use some eslint rule to improve your code.

For example:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => { 
   return { 
      principal: state.form.principal
   }; 
};
```

could be:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ 
   principal: state.form.principal 
});
```

And the statefull class could be stateless class:

```
const App = ({ principal, principalChanged }) => ( 
            <Card>
               <Input 
                 placeholder="Placeholder" 
                 label="Label" 
                 onChangeText={principalChanged} 
                 value={principal}                      
                />
              `Current state of the variable: ${principal}`{/n}
              `New variable: ${principal2}`
              `New variable: ${principal3}`
            </Card>
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?
Shall principal2 and principal3 be components, or just functions? They are imported from the directory "components", so I assume they are components? If so, you first need to return any kind or component, not only a number. Like:

```
export const principal2 = ({ value}) => {     
   return <span>{ value * 2 }</span>; // calculating 
};
```

Then use the component like:

```
New variable: <principal value={anyNumber} />
```

In case of "normal" function use principal like:

```
New variable: {principal(anyNumber)}
```

Btw: you don´t need to put the strings in these little quotes "`". You can write

```
New variable: {principal3}
```

within your return value of the component.